# Prevent appspec from running scripts (disable hooks)

Tags: aws-code-deploy

I'm new to codedeploy. I managed to make a deployment to an ec2 instance successfully (and using git to manage code so everything works beautifully now).

I want some other people besides myself working in the project to be able to deploy source code to the instance but not be able to run a script (especially because codedeploy seems to be running as root). Think of it as an admin/webmaster scenario.

In other words, appspec.yml has the "hooks" section under it and you can run any scripts as part of the deployment. I want to prevent this, the instance has all the software ready for the deployment so won't be needing this.

2 questions:
1) Does this make sense or am I grossly misunderstanding something/am I overkilling by using codedeploy altogether?
2) If it makes sense, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem to be something that CodeDeploy is able to do at this moment. But do you want to disable the auto deploy from Github to CodeDeploy? And if anyone else push a code change, it'll exist on Github. When you are ok with the changes, you can do a manually deployment from Github on CodeDeploy console.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea. I guess it'll work if I limit the deploy rights to myself and if I commit with my version of appspec.yml (just to be on the safe side) before the deployment.